# Encryption Details of filesystem backend for Hashicorp Vault Community Edition

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I cannot find any information about how the filesystem storage backend encrypts data at rest in the Hashicorp Vault Community Edition. Does anyone know the details of the encryption cipher(s), hashing algorithms, etc.? Is it configurable or is there a way to inspect the ciphers on an existing filesystem vault?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [official documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/internals/security.html):

> Vault uses a security barrier for all requests made to the backend. The security barrier automatically encrypts all data leaving Vault using a 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) cipher in the Galois Counter Mode (GCM) with 96-bit nonces.

So the cipher used for storing secrets is an AES 256 with GMC. I think that this is an architecturale choise that cannot be changed.

Comment: I read that in the docs but I didn't think it applied because it specifically says, "all data leaving Vault". So you think it applies to data at rest in the filesystem backend also?

Comment: If you refer to the [file system storage backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/filesystem.html) yes, it's encrypted with AES. All the storage backends uses that encryption. And the the "data leaving Vault" refers to the data that will be stored and managed by Vault in the storage backend. Remember that Vault is not the phisical place where data is stored, it's the tool that allows you to manage and store data securely.